# laravel 5.4 show, edit and delete is not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

**controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Role;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Html\FormFacade;

class RoleController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            $roles = Role::orderBy('name','asc')->get();
            return view('role.index', ['roles' => $roles]);
        }
        public function create()
        {
            return view('role.create');
        }
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|unique:roles|string|max:100',
            ]);
            $role = Role::create(['name' => $request->name]);
            $role->save();
            return Redirect::route('roles.index');
        }
        public function show(Role $role)
        {
            $roles = Role::find($role); 
            return view('role.show',  ['roles' => $roles]);
        }  
        public function edit(Role $role)
        {
            $roles = Role::find($role);
            //dd($roles);
            return view('role.edit', compact('role')); 
        }
        public function update(Request $request, Role $role)
        {
            $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:40|unique:roles,name,' .$role
            ]);

            $role = Role::find($role);
            $role->update(['name' => $request->name]);
            //dd($role->update(['name' => $request->name]));
            return Redirect::route('roles.show', ['role' => $role]);
        }
        public function destroy(Role $role)
        {
            //$song =  Song::where('slug', $slug)->delete();
            $role =  Role::where('id', $role)->delete();
            dd($role);
            //Role::destroy($role);
            return Redirect::route('roles.index');
        }
    }
```

**model**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Role extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('base.master')
@section('title')
<title>Models</title>
@endsection
@section('content')
<div class="col-lg-12">
@if(Session::has('success_msg'))
<div class="alert alert-success">{{ Session::get('success_msg') }}</div>
@endif
<!-- Posts list -->
@if(!empty($roles))
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <h2>Roles List </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('roles.create') }}"> Add New</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-striped task-table">
            <!-- Table Headings -->
            <thead>
            <th width="25%">Name</th>
            <th width="20%">Action</th>
            </thead>

            <!-- Table Body -->
            <tbody>
                @foreach($roles as $role)
                <tr>
                    <td class="table-text">
                        <div>{{$role->name}}</div>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ route('roles.show', $role->id) }}" class="label label-success">Details</a>
                        <a href="{{ route('roles.edit', $role->id) }}" class="label label-warning">Edit</a>

                        <a href="{{ route('roles.destroy', $role->id) }}" class="label label-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
</div>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
<script>
    function ConfirmDelete()
    {
    var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
    return x;
    }
</script>
@endsection
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
@extends('base.master')
@section('title')
<title>Edit Model</title>
@endsection
@section('content')
<h1>Edit Roles</h1>
<hr/>
<!--{{ $role }}-->
<form class="form" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/roles/'. $role->id) }}">
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
{{ csrf_field() }}
<!-- Role Name Form Input -->
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ $role->name }}">
    @if ($errors->has('name'))
    <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
    </span>
    @endif
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
        Edit
    </button>
</div>
</form>
@endsection
```

**show.blade.php**

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
            <h2>Role Detalis</h2>
        </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
            <a href="{{ route('roles.index') }}" class="label label-primary pull-right"> Back</a>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div       <div class="row">
@foreach ($roles as $role)
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Name:</strong>
            <p>{{strtolower($role->name)}}</p>  
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Published On:</strong>
        {{ $role->created_at->format('d M Y - H:i:s')  }}
    </div>
    </div>
 @endforeach
    </div>
```

**Question: 1** 
       On delete it goes to details page.

**Question:2**
       After edit it shows ->

> (2/2) QueryException SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown
>   column 'name:"222"' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as
>   aggregate from `roles` where `name` = user and `name:"222"` <> {"id":3
>   and `created_at:"2017-11-17 10:50:13"` = updated_at:"2017-11-17
>   10:50:13"})

**Question: 3** 
     On delete it goes to show page.

**Question:4**
     Find for single value is not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel uses `DELETE` request to go to delete function.
If you try to run: `php artisan route:list` you can find that `roles.destroy` route is called only in `DELETE` request.
So replace this line `<a href="{{ route('roles.destroy', $role->id) }}" class="label label-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')">Delete</a>` to something like below,

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('roles.destroy', $role->id) }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="deleteForm">
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
{{ scrf_field() }}
<button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')" class="label label-danger">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you didn't go through the documentation properly and messed up completely. updating your controller have a look and try again.

```
class RoleController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $roles = Role::orderBy('name','asc')->get();
        return view('role.index', ['roles' => $roles]);
    }
    public function create()
    {
        return view('role.create');
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|unique:roles|string|max:100',
        ]);
        $role = Role::create(['name' => $request->name]);
        $role->save();
        return Redirect::route('roles.index');
    }
    public function show($id)
    {
        $role = Role::find($id); 
        return view('role.show',  ['roles' => $role]);
    }  
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $role = Role::find($id);
        return view('role.edit', compact('role')); 
    }
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:40|unique:roles,name'
        ]);

        $role = Role::find($id);
        $role->update(['name' => $request->name]);
        return Redirect::route('roles.show', ['role' => $role]);
    }
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $role =  Role::where('id', $id)->delete();
        return Redirect::route('roles.index');
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. update is not working.
2. After clicking delete function ,it goes to show function